# To Use urldecode() or Not When Outputting User Submitted Details From Your Database?

Tags: php, html, filter

I am struggling to understand whether to use urldecode() or not as I read in tutorials that the browser auto url decodes encoded urls and so we don't have to urldecode().
I need to filter the user inputs before they submit their data to my Mysql database. And I need to secure filter too before displaying their data on my pages.

CODE A

```
<?php

function test_input($data)
{
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data); //Strips only Backward Slashes. Not Forward Slashes.
        
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
$data = strip_tags($data);
$data = urlencode($data);


return $data;
}

$input_2 = 'http://www.url.com/index.php';
$input_3 = '<a href="http://www.url.com/index.php">Link</a> *';

echo test_input($input_3);

?>
```

But why isn't the above echoing a decoded url if the browser auto decodes, that is ?

I get echoed:
**%26lt%3Ba+href%3D%26quot%3Bhttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Findex.php%26quot%3B%26gt%3BLink%26lt%3B%2Fa%26gt%3B+%2A**

And this code:
CODE B

```
<?php

function test_input($data)
{
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data); //Strips only Backward Slashes. Not Forward Slashes.
        
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
$data = strip_tags($data);
$data = urlencode($data);


return $data;
}

$input_2 = 'http://www.url.com/index.php';
$input_3 = '<a href="http://www.url.com/index.php">Link</a> *';

echo test_input(urldecode($input_3));

?>
```

Outputs this:
**%26lt%3Ba+href%3D%26quot%3Bhttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.url.com%2Findex.php%26quot%3B%26gt%3BLink%26lt%3B%2Fa%26gt%3B+%2A**

They both output the same. Note the 2nd code uses urldecode() while the 1st code doesn't. Hence, they shouldn't output the same. Correct ?

How to fix so url is echoed in decoded format ?
NOTE: The custom function is a filter that filters user's inputs. Trying to build a filter so users can submit the following details that get filtered before submission to my db and gets filtered before getting echoed or displayed on my pages.

```
<form method = 'POST' action = "$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']">
<label for='find'>Find</label>
<input type='text' name='find' id='find'>
<br>
Table:
<input type='radio' name='table' id='sale'><label for='table'>Businesses On Sale</label>
<input type='radio' name='table' id='sold'><label for='table'>Businesses Sold</label>
<br>
<label for="column">Column:</label>
<select name="column" id="column">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="business_submission_id">Business Submission Id</option>
    <option value="business_submission_date_and_time">Business Submission Date & Time</option>
    <option value="business_name">Business Name</option>
    <option value="business_zip">Business Zip</option>
    <option value="business_phone">Business Phone</option>
    <option value="business_email">Business Email</option>
    <option value="business_domain">Business Website Domain Name</option>
    <option value="business_url">Business Website Url</option>
    <option value="business_description">Business Description</option>
    </select>
<button type='submit'>Submit!</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Clean data when you store it!! It may not be the same application that is using/reading it later

Comment: @RiggsFolly, Care to show me a sample how to clean the data you see that gets submitted via my form ?

Comment: @RiggsFolly — That's a reason to **not** clean it when you store it. If you clean it for inserting into an HTML document and store it and then later a different applications reads it and puts it in a text email then the HTML encoding is going to break it.

Comment: Ok @Quentin I dont consider doing a `urlencode()` on data Before storing it as a sensible clean up, so I may have got the wrong end of the stick on this one

Comment: in face that function `test_input($data)` looks very like the good old Infamous pre store cleaner that should never have been posted on the internet

Answer (score 1):

This is what you are doing:

```
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data); //Strips only Backward Slashes. Not Forward Slashes.
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
$data = strip_tags($data);
$data = urlencode($data);
```

1. Removing white space from the ends (generally a good idea)
2. Removing slashes (generally not a good idea, it's a destructive and ineffective security measure)
3. Making the data suitable for inserting as text into an HTML document.
4. Removing tags (generally not a good idea as it is destructive, but entirely pointless here because `htmlspecialchars` will have replaced all the characters that `strip_tags` operates on.
5. Making the data suitable for inserting into a URL
6. Echoing the whole thing

Focusing on the two that matter for this scenario.

Normally you have some input which you want to put into a URL and then put that URL into an HTML document:

```
$foo = "some unsafe user input";
$query_foo = urlencode($foo);   // Now safe to be inserted into a URL
$url = "http://example.com/?query=$query_foo";
$html_url = htmlspecialchars($url);
?><a href="<?=$html_url ?>">...</a><?php
```

In your case you are inserting the content into a URL at all, so you shouldn't use `urlencode` on it. `urlencode` isn't for **whole** URLs (unless you are making a whole URL a query string value of another URL).

You're also making it safe to be inserted into HTML before you put it into the URL, which is backwards because the URL would be inside the HTML document, not the other way around.

> But why isn't the above echoing a decoded url if the browser auto decodes, that is ?

The browser decodes a properly encoded URL for the purposes of displaying in the address bar when you visit that URL and for displaying in the "where this link goes" status area when you hover over a link.

You've just dropping the data as text in HTML, you aren't navigating to it and it isn't part of a link.

> They both output the same. Note the 2nd code uses urldecode() while the 1st code doesn't. Hence, they shouldn't output the same. Correct ?

You have it backwards again.

You are decoding the string (which has no `%` encoded characters in it so that has no effect) and then encoding it and then echoing the encoded version.

Comment: Thanks you for your response. One thing you misunderstood, though. I aint trying to filter user's inputs that will form part of a url. I am building a searchengine where user's will submit their links to my db. then, I will echo their submitted links based on keyword searches. So the webform html you see, is what the users use to submit their links (along with their business website descriptions).

Comment: I just wanted to filter their submissions before my db accepts their submissions. And I wanted to filter again before outputting their links on my SERPS just incase somehow the visitor (hacker, etc.) who does the keyword search somehow manages to inject some code that interferes or forms part of the output.

Comment: "One thing you misunderstood, though. I aint trying to filter user's inputs that will form part of a url." — Then you shouldn't go anywhere near urlencode/decode.

Comment: "I am building a searchengine where user's will submit their links to my db. then, I will echo their submitted links based on keyword searches." — Then you should use SQL placeholders to protect the DB and `htmlspecialchars` to protect the HTML document as per the example in this answer.

Comment: I believe you are right! Thanks for bringing me to my senses. Lately, been too much into urlencode(), rawurlencode(), htmlentities(), htmlspecialentities(), intval() that I now got my wires crossed.

Comment: After knowing what I want filtered. Can you now show me a code sample of how the function test_input($data) should look like because I sure have messed it up.

Comment: Not really. You shouldn't be using anything like it.

Comment: One other question. In tutorials, they show, to inlcude all those that you see in my function test_input($data) apart from the urlencode() which I added myself. My question is, why they add htmlspecialchars() a limited character encoder over the htmlentities() which deals with more characters than the other ? Should I stick with the former or latter here ?

Comment: Escaped characters take up more bandwidth. Escaping things which aren't handled by `htmlspecialchars` is unnecessary now we have decent support for UTF-8 (i.e. now we are in the 21st century)

Comment: Thanks for the elaboration. Sticking to hmtlspecialchars() then.